# US Visa DS 160 and appointment

Tags: visas, usa

I recently completed the DS 160 form and sent it to an agent to assess it, the agent didn't know I had already created my profile in Cgi federal for an appointment and paying visa fees. So, he created another one in my name through which he gave the info sheet to pay the visa fees. The one I created I only stopped at visa class and it doesn't have all information including passport and all of that, it only has my full name in it. What should I do? Would that be a problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should be fine.

At some point I had two accounts with all DS-160 details filled in because I've lost access to the earlier one.

Make sure you reference correct application number and don't mix them up.